# How is it done that global sides with millions of users are so fast?

Tags: file, query-optimization, database-connection

could you please help me with some reference/literature/source/web where I can find more information about ways to optimize a site with a lot of data inside. The goal is to create a site where everyone can access data/files and do not need to use i.e. MS terminal or vmware viewer to access data from our other location. Should I invest into internal servers or look for cloud? I would like to know where to start. It's question from dummy, but thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

One of the aspects that make sites like facebook, google, and so on so fast is that they replicate their servers in different part of the world so users do not have the latency that occurs when you try to contact a website on the other side of the world.

The servers used are also very high end so they are able to handle a lot of simultaneous requests at a time.

And finally probably one of the most important aspect is that the database schemas, the code and the architecture are constantly refined to work as fast as possible.